# Instantiate a QObject class while appending to a QList

Tags: qt

I have following code:

```
MyListViewItemDataSubListItem *subItem = NULL;
QList<QObject*> subListNumberOfPlayers;

//this works but is a bit long ;-)
subItem = new MyListViewItemDataSubListItem(this, "10");
subListNumberOfPlayers.append(subItem);
subItem = new MyListViewItemDataSubListItem(this, "9");
subListNumberOfPlayers.append(subItem);
subItem = new MyListViewItemDataSubListItem(this, "8");
subListNumberOfPlayers.append(subItem);
subItem = new MyListViewItemDataSubListItem(this, "7");
subListNumberOfPlayers.append(subItem);
```

Is it also possible to do the following instead? Or better ... could there be any unwanted side effects or misbehaviour when i do it like this?

```
subListNumberOfPlayers.append(new MyListViewItemDataSubListItem(this, "10"));
subListNumberOfPlayers.append(new MyListViewItemDataSubListItem(this, "9"));
subListNumberOfPlayers.append(new MyListViewItemDataSubListItem(this, "8"));
subListNumberOfPlayers.append(new MyListViewItemDataSubListItem(this, "7"));
```

Comment: why don't you try? it's faster :)

Comment: So long as `MyListViewItemDataSubListItem` (which should deffo be shortened imo) is derived from `QObject` then it's valid.

Comment: Question is about basic of programing which could be checked if you simply try to do it.

Comment: Sorry i have to change my question. I tried it and it works, but i want to know if there could be unwanted side effects when i do it like this ...

Comment: There can't be any unwanted side effects from not using the temporary pointer variable. In fact, using it is introducing a chance for errors, so unless it had helped readability (it doesn't here!), you shouldn't be writing it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no side effects, but using `append` is *still* long. You can initialize the whole list in one go:

```
auto subListNumberOfPlayers = QList<QObject*>()
  << new MyListViewItemDataSubListItem(this, "10")
  << new MyListViewItemDataSubListItem(this, "9")
  << new MyListViewItemDataSubListItem(this, "8")
  << new MyListViewItemDataSubListItem(this, "7");
```

If you care about the last bit of performance, you could reserve space in the list so that it has space for all the items you wish to insert, without having to reallocate. `std::list` doesn't provide that interface, but `QList` does. For small numbers of items, the first append (`<<`) will already allocate enough space, so the explicit call isn't needed here.

You could also use `std::list` and store object values, but that will only work if all your instances are of the same type.

```
std::list<MyListViewItemDataSubListItem> l;
l.emplace_back(this, "10");
l.emplace_back(this, "9");
l.emplace_back(this, "8");
l.emplace_back(this, "7");
auto & subListNumberOfPlayers = l;
```

If you really want to get concise, you can use the fact that the sequence of constructor arguments is easy to generate. It's useful to `reserve` the space here, as the loop is flexible:

```
const int n = 4;
QList<QObject*> subListNumberOfPlayers;
subListNumberOfPlayers.reserve(n);
for (int i = 10; i > (10-n); --i) subListNumberOfPlayers
  << new MyListViewItemDataSubListItem(this, QString::number(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, but this way you don't have a chance to check if `new` returns a zero in case something goes wrong. It is *possible* that you append a zero and get a crash later when you attempt to use it.

Comment: In which case "new" could return a zero?

Comment: @fhammer - normally it will throw an exception, but if you don't want to deal with that you can use the nothrow version, which will simply return zero if allocation fails.

Comment: @ddriver In most cases, once a nothrow `new` returns zero, there's nothing you can do - at least not unless you're very careless and audit all the code that will execute once that has happened. You can pretty much exclude any sort of user interaction at that point, etc., unless you can quickly free quite a bit of memory. Generally speaking, such concerns only make sense when a relatively big allocation fails. If a small one fails, there's nothing you can do without freeing lots of memory.

Comment: @KubaOber yes this is true, as a habit from C I still use returning null a lot in cases such as failure to find something. Unlike with `new`, it does make sense to check what you are adding before you add it. In such a case exceptions are overkill, especially if there is a workaround in a case of a null.